# is there a method for binding newline in .bashrc?

Tags: bash

Being able to define something like `bind -x '"\n": | capture \n'` or `bind -x '"\n": | capture ;'` would be nice. It could make me run a command (e.g. capture) in bash each time i press enter.

Comment: Questions about _interactive_ shell configuration, as opposed to script development, are generally more appropriate to [unix.se].

Comment: In addition to `PROMPT_COMMAND`, there's also [`PS0`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-PS0) which might be useful, depending on what exactly you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work as expected :

```
bind 'Return:"|capture\n"'
```

Answer (score 3):

`bash` has the [PROMPT_COMMAND](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x264.html) environment variable that may be of use.  This designates a command to run *before* displaying your command prompt which in your case should behave the same as pressing 'Enter'.

Example:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="echo 'hello' | sed 's/hello/good-bye/g'"
```

Each time I press 'Enter' it will display `good-bye` at the console:

```
$                               # press 'Enter'
good-bye
$                               # press 'Enter'
good-bye
$                               # press 'Enter'
good-bye
```

'course this also applies if you actually run something at the command prompt though the `good-bye` is displayed after the 'something' completes, eg:

```
$ date
Fri Aug 18 09:30:34 CDT 2023
good-bye
$ echo 'here I am'
here I am
good-bye
```

Keep in mind this action is not 'bound' to the 'Enter' key but rather 'bound' to the display of a new command prompt.  In the following the first two times we press 'Enter' we embed a newline in the input and it isn't until after the 3rd 'Enter' that the command is processed and *then* the `PROMPT_COMMAND` action is performed:

```
$ echo "a                       # press 'Enter'
> b                             # press 'Enter'
> c"                            # press 'Enter'
a
b
c
good-bye
```

**NOTE:** run `unset PROMPT_COMMAND` to disable/remove this behavior

Answer (score 1):

You can choose two key sequences you are unlikely to enter. (Control sequences may be a good choice.)

Then:

```
bind -x '"unlikelykeysequence1":yourCommand'
bind '"unlikelykeysequence2":accept-line'
bind 'Return:"unlikelykeysequence1unlikelykeysequence2"'
```